# Wrong wiring in a transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, cmos

[image]

This circuit confused me, when A=0 the PMOS (assuming its source is connected to the power supply, because it's not mentioned by the exercise) will be ON so the circuit between the power supply and Out is short, does this mean it'll be one? I'm not sure. And when A=1 the NMOS will be on so there will be a short circuit between the power supply and ground, I know transistor circuits shouldn't work like this, but this is a wrong wiring so will the Out be floating, or will this short circuit affect the value in Out?

Exercise source: *Introduction to Computing Systems from Bits and Gates to C/C++ & Beyond* by Yale N. Patt and Sanjay J. Pattel, Third Edition Published by McGraw-Hill Education

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct.

When A=0, Out = 1
When A=1, Out = floating and the NMOS may get damaged. If the power supply is not able to provide the current, it's value may drop to a low value and that could affect the value of Out due to the drain-bulk diode.

[image]

Edit: I have updated the PMOS to show the bulk connection and the drain to bulk diode. So, if power supply is 0V, there is a diode from Out to 0V. Out is still floating but it's value will be less than Vsupply + diode voltage.

Comment: What value may drop to a low value? I think that when A=1 the Out wire won't be connected to the rest of the circuit so it'll just be floating

Comment: The power supply could drop to a low value. For eg., if supply is 5V, when A=1, the supply could even drop close to 0V if the power supply cannot supply the high current that starts flowing because the NMOS is fully turned ON. In the PMOS symbol you do not show the bulk terminal. I'll add that in my answer and provide more explanation

Answer (score 0):

The question explicitly asks what was done wrong, and you analysis is spot on.  The circuit shown will short the supple when the bottom FET turns on, and most likely let out the "magic smoke".